# Was Star Wars influenced by The Six Million Dollar Man?

Tags: star-wars, science-fiction, the-six-million-dollar-man

I recently started to rewatch episodes of *The Six Million Dollar Man* which was a favorite of mine as a kid in the 70s.  It has been a while since I've seen it so I sought out some of the more iconic episodes from memory.  And of course what is more iconic than the story arcs that involved bigfoot and the aliens?

I made it to the 1st episode of season 4 titled "The Return of Bigfoot: Part 1", and while playing it a particular scene struck a chord.

About 00:16:00 in, the main antagonist/mastermind Nedlick (played by the awesome John Saxon) is dressing down a minion named Faler for challenging his evil master plan.  "Your lack of patience is extremely trying, Faler", he says.  Nedlick then summons the nearby Sasquatch (dreadful robot) to intimidate Faler.

So, we have
the main villain/major character challenging an incidental character in a personal confrontation:

> NEDLICK:  Your lack of patience is extremely trying, Faler.

The main villain then displays his terrible power by demonstrating his command of Sasquatch.

This struck me as very reminiscent of the scene in Star Wars (A New Hope) when Darth Vader is dressing down Admiral Motti.

Again we have the main villain/major character challenging an incidental character in a personal confrontation:

> VADER:  I find your lack of faith disturbing.

The main villain then displays his terrible power by demonstrating his command of The Force.

OK.  Amusing anecdote, I thought.

Then about 00:24:00 in there is a scene where the most sexy of the female alien characters named Shalon tries to recruit Steve Austin (main protagonist) into getting involved in the crisis at hand through a video.  She ends with "Thank you for helping us, Steve.  You are our only hope now".  Then the diminishing quality feed fades out.

So, now we have an appeal to a hero/major character from a damsel in distress/major character via a video facsimile with fadeout:

> SHALON:  Thank you for helping us, Steve.  You are our only hope now.

Which once again struck me as remarkably similar to the iconic scene in Star Wars with Princess Leia's desperate recording for Obi-Wan which was also an appeal to a hero/major character from a damsel in distress/major character via a video facsimile with fadeout:

> LEIA:  Help me, Obi-Wan Kenobi. You're my only hope.

Then there are the similarities between Sasquatch and Chewbacca, not only in appearance but with the whole "misunderstood beast" motif throughout.

Now a pattern begins to emerge.  Are the similarities pure coincidence?  Synchronicity?  Or was there some kind of industry cross-pollination going on?

Here are the production facts that I've been able to find.

According to IMDb.com, "Star Wars: Episode IV - A New Hope" was filmed between March 22, 1976 and July 16, 1976.

"The Return of Bigfoot: Part 1" first aired in the US on September 19, 1976 -- two months after the last day of filming for Star Wars.  It's my layman's understanding that during this period of TV production it was typical for there to be a 6 to 9 month lag between final shooting of an episode and its airing.  If we assume that it took a month to shoot the episode (probably over-generous), then it means shooting would have begun sometime between November 1975 and February 1976.  Which means the final draft of the script for the episode would have been needed no later than February 1976.  Which was a month before Star Wars began filming.

It is also the case that the script for Star Wars would have been needed in advance of filming.  But according to IMSDb.com the working script for Star Wars was a 4th draft revision dated January 15, 1976.  Could the more recent revisions of it have included scenes that were inspired by the *Six* pre-production?

So it is conceivable that there was a multi-month period during the pre-production of both where the scripts for both were being actively developed simultaneously, presenting the opportunity for cross-influence.  This particular *Six* script was especially important to ABC because it was also going to be the launch pad for their new spinoff series *The Bionic Woman* which they had very high hopes for.  So it potentially had an elevated exposure around town.

If one believes that there must have been more than coincidence involved here, as I am inclined to, then the question becomes:   *What was the common link between the two productions that resulted in this cross-influence?*

Looking at the production credits of both I can find no obvious smoking guns.

---

Update

Thanks to the link from Valorum I was able to find the 3rd draft script which preceded the final 4th (http://www.scifiscripts.com/scripts/star_wars_3rd.txt).  It does not contain either of the scenes mentioned above.  There is no Vader "your lack of" scene confronting Motti, and R2D2's message from Leia has a totally different dialog with no "only hope" appeal to any specific hero.  It was dated August 1 1975 which was less than 6 months from the final draft.  This period was also likely the period when the *Six* episode script was being developed, further supporting the cross-influence theory.

Chewbacca as a tall monkey-like character was introduced in the 2nd draft script which was dated January 1 1975 (http://www.scifiscripts.com/scripts/SWSECOND.TXT).
Sasquatch was introduced in season 3 episode 17 "The Secret of Bigfoot: Part 1" which was aired February 1 1976.  Assuming again that there was a 6-9 month lag between production and release that suggests its script would have been finalized no later than August 1975 and possibly some months earlier.  Again a case of similar story elements being introduced into the scripts within 6 months of each other.

It's worth noting though that there was a resurgence of interest in Bigfoot/Sasquatch in the US in the early '70s, so even if there was cross-influence with other story elements it is also possible that with this one both scripts simply responded to the zeitgeist of the times.

Comment: http://www.scifiscripts.com/scripts/star_wars_1st_7_74.txt - 1974 draft.

Comment: There's a couple of crossovers, but nothing of any note; https://www.imdb.com/search/name/?roles=tt0076759,tt0071054

Comment: Equally, or perhaps more likely, is that both are drawing from the same earlier influences.

Comment: @Valorum those were very useful links.  Thanks.

Comment: @ToddWilcox Agreed.  I wonder if both scripts might have been doctored by some of the same individuals and they included these story elements from some other project that may never have been produced.

Comment: @dhinson919 - I don't think so. There aren't really any 'secret' script doctors involved in Star Wars

Comment: I don't know about secret, but according to IMDb there were two uncredited people with the titles Script Doctor in the Script and Continuity Department, Willard Huyck and Gloria Katz.  Both were co-writers of American Graffiti and would go on to develop the screenplay for Indiana Jones and the Temple of Doom.  Both of those movies are considered to be well-written, so if I had to wager on who was responsible for morphing Lucas's 3rd draft Star Wars script into the 4th draft that made it to the screen it would be one or both of them.  But if either had ties to TSMDM I can't find it.